# Disable Networking in Electron

Tags: node.js, security, networking, electron, malware

[electron.js](https://electronjs.org/) is a user interface toolkit that allows a web application to operate as an arbitrary GUI.

However, there are some applications that should be considered sensitive - for instance, a GUI for banking should have strong assurances that it's not doing anything mischievous.

I'm wondering if the electron executable (or node.js itself) would allow operation in a mode where networking is outright *disabled* - that way, as a consumer, I can at least be confident a user interface isn't sending my password off-site.

Something like `./node_modules/.bin/electron --no-networking index.js` would be very convenient, albeit a far cry.

Comment: Great question! Did you end up finding a solution to reliably disable networking capabilities in Electron app?

Comment: See https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#12-disable-or-limit-navigation

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried whether it works or not.
The following lines simulate the offline mode in chromium.

// To emulate a network outage.

```
window.webContents.session.enableNetworkEmulation({ offline: true });
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think I have seen an open WebSocket connection exchange messages even when network emulation was enabled, so maybe it's not 100% fool-proof.