# How to disable networking in Electron app?

Tags: electron

I am developing an offline app and would like to disable networking for security purposes.

Is that possible? If so, how? Thanks for helping out!

Comment: By networking, do you mean if the BrowserWindow tries to navigate to a URL that's not a local file then it should be stopped?

Comment: Thanks for helping out @Joshua. I would like to disable all networking features so app cannot connect to the Internet. If a package tries to call home, for example. Btw, I am new to Electron, so perhaps this is done by default.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953464/disable-networking-in-electron

Answer (score 1):

**This answer only works on the renderer process, not on the main process**

You may want to use network emulation:

```js
const { session } = require('electron');

session.defaultSession.enableNetworkEmulation({
  offline: true,
});

// Or

window.webContents.session.enableNetworkEmulation({
  offline: true,
});
```

It probably is equivalent to opening the devtools and using network throttling.

On the documentation: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/session#sesenablenetworkemulationoptions

Comment: Interesting use of `enableNetworkEmulation`. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: My gut feeling is that this solution would not prevent rogue npm package from calling home at the Node level. Correct?

Comment: Yeah it wouldn't prevent the main process from connecting to the internet, I'm not really sure if there's a way to prevent the whole app from conecting to the internet, maybe with App Store or Microsoft Store signing that does not give the internet permission? but I've never used signing so I have no idea of it's capabilities.